# How do I redirect Ansible to use files in a role directory?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, infrastructure-as-code

Salutations, I am deploying pods/applications to EKS via Ansible. My playbook runs a few `kubectl apply -f` commands in order to deploy EKS resources and all of the .yaml files are in that directory.

I would like to place these .yaml files that create each application in it's own *ansible role/files* directory in order to clean up the main ansible directory a bit (the .yaml files are becoming overwhelming and I only have two applications being deployed thus far).

The issue is this: When I move the .yaml files to it's respective */roles/files* directory ansible still seems to look for the files in the main ansible directory instead of scanning the internal role directory.

How do I redirect Ansible to run the shell commands on .yamls in the role's file directory? Playbook below:

```
#
# Deploying Jenkins to AWS EKS
#
# Create Jenkins Namespace
- name: Create Jenkins Namespace & set it to default
  shell: |
    kubectl create namespace jenkins
    kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=jenkins
# Create Jenkins Service Account
- name: Create Jenkins Service Account
  shell: |
    kubectl create serviceaccount jenkins-master -n jenkins
    kubectl get secret $(kubectl get sa jenkins-master -n jenkins -o jsonpath={.secrets[0].name}) -n jenkins -o jsonpath={.data.'ca\.crt'} | base64 --decode
# Deploy Jenkins
- name: Deploy Jenkins Application
  shell: | 
    kubectl apply -f jenkins-service.yaml
    kubectl apply -f jenkins-vol.yaml
    kubectl apply -f jenkins-role.yaml
    kubectl apply -f jenkins-configmap.yaml
    kubectl apply -f jenkins-deployment.yaml
```

Below is the role directory structure, Ansible doesn't check this location for the yaml files to run in the playbook above.
[image: This is the directory structure]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `role_path` variable, which contains the path to the currently executing role. You could write your tasks like:

```
- name: Deploy Jenkins Application
  shell: | 
    kubectl apply -f {{ role_path }}/files/jenkins-service.yaml
    kubectl apply -f {{ role_path }}/files/jenkins-vol.yaml
    ...
```

Alternately, a `fileglob` lookup might be easier:

```
- name: Deploy Jenkins Application
  command: kubectl apply -f {{ item }}
  loop: "{{ query('fileglob', '*.yaml') }}"
```

This would loop over all the `*.yaml` files in your role's `files`
directory.

You could consider replacing your use of `kubectl` with
the [k8s module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/kubernetes/k8s_module.html).

Lastly, rather than managing these resources using Ansible, you could
consider using [kustomize](https://kustomize.io/), which I have found
to be easier to work with unless you're relying heavily on Ansible
templating.